# Android when insert data doesn't store into database

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to insert data into database SQLLite, but the data doesn't go into database:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("username", cust.getUsername());
            cv.put("password", cust.getPassword());
            cv.put("name", cust.getCustomername());
            long id = mDb.insert("user", null, cv);
            Log.v(TAG, Long.toString(id));
            Log.e(TAG, "New Customer Created");
            return true;
```

The id returns 5, any idea why? (After few times insert the id return 7 now.)

What other code should I post here? The database connection should be fine since I am able to log-in successfully.

Comment: can you post your database oncreate method

Comment: Please check your column name like user-name or password & name please post your table structure

Comment: Do you close your database connection afterwards? If not, this could cause the error.
( `mDb.close();` )

Comment: change the return type to long data type

Comment: @KingCobraa am using SQLiteDatabase in my DatabaseHelper the onCreate method is empty

Comment: @YogeshTatwal is the sequence and case sensitive affected? I got a 4 column id is auto increment, username, password, and name

Comment: I got do mDb.close(); after insert

Comment: yes case sensitive will effect

Comment: if your onCreate() in database helper is empty then how would you insert data in table. cause there is no table according to you

Comment: Have you got solution

Comment: @KingCobraa that means my all insert method has to create inside DatabaseHelper the onCreate method?

Comment: no man i am asking where are you creating table.

Comment: @YogeshTatwal I haven't found the  solution

Comment: Where am I creating table? I am creating the table using SQLite Database Browser and the db file stored in assets folder. There is a user table with 4 columns.

Comment: post your screen-shot of table

Comment: I think the data got inserted into database, but I browse through theSQLite Database Browser the data wasn't go in.

Comment: if you want to check if db is created and what is written, run apk on emulator, open Android Monitor Tool, navigate to File Explorer to /data/data/<your-apk-package>/databases/<yourdbname>.db, copy this file to your computer and open it with any SQLite manager e.g. SQLiteman

Comment: @robotoaster thanks got it, is it possible to get the file out?

Comment: I have added answer below with a screengrab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check what is really inserted into db download database file from emulator. You may use Android Debug Monitor

[image: Android Debug Monitor]

Then open database in any SQLite client

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned your database is stored in your asset folder. Every file in the assets or resources is readonly. You have to copy the database file to another path to write data into it.

Here is some code for the `SQLiteOpenHelper`:

```
 public static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String ASSET_DB_DIRECTORY = "db";
    private static final String DATABASE_RESOURCE_PATH = ASSET_DB_DIRECTORY + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME;

    private final Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void createDatabase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{
            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean checkDatabase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        File file = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(file.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //database does't exist yet.
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
            if(file.lastModified() != new File(DATABASE_RESOURCE_PATH).lastModified())
                return false;
        }
        return checkDB != null;
    }

    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException{
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_RESOURCE_PATH);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        //Open the database
        String myPath = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        return db;
    }
```